# in eclipse error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32.exe");

    FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //This is the location where you have installed Firefox on your machine

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist: E:\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32.exe

Why is this error? path of geckodriver-v0.16.1-win32.exe is correct. what should I do?

Comment: Are you sure you machine is 32 bit? and 32 bit firefox? Have you downloaded from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) which is a zip file. Have you extracted exe file out of it? is the name correct?

Comment: try `File pathBinary = new File("C:\\program files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();       
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, firefoxProfile);` to set your FF binary path

Comment: @RaviAnand I have a solution for you but I need a clarification what is the reason for using `options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")` ? Do you have multiple Mozila Firefox installations?

Comment: @Rao I am using 64 bit machine and 64 bit firefox.

Comment: @kausal thanks. it works

Comment: @Dev No, I have only one Mozilla firefox (64 bit)

Comment: @RaviAnand, you were using 32 firefox. Because the path was referred from `C:\\Program Files (x86)`. Looks it worked after  switching to 64-bit ff based on the above comments.

Comment: So your issue is solved. Right?